# Substituting each row of col1 into the corresponding token in col2 using the apply family

Tags: r

I feel like this has to be a super basic thing to solve but my searching skills are failing me.

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("abc", "def", "ghi"),
                 col2 = c("foo ~xyz~", "~xyz~ bar", "blah ~xyz~ blah"))
col1   col2
abc    foo ~xyz~
def    ~xyz~ bar
ghi    blah ~xyz~ blah
```

I want to `gsub()` each row of `col1` into the corresponding `~xyz~` token in `col2`. The desired output is:

```
col1   col2
abc    foo abc   
def    def bar
ghi    blah ghi blah
```

I can solve this using a `for` loop but I feel like there's got to be a way to do this with `vapply` or `sapply`.

My `for` loop solution is as follows:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
     itemhold <- df$col1[i]
     df$col2[i] <- gsub("~xyz~", itemhold, df$col2[i])
}
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated. If it's not painfully obvious by now, I'm fairly new to R and it's my first language.

**Edit:** I deleted some stuff about a function I used for these purposes because as I actually worked through my minrep example I realized it wasn't needed--I use the function in a special case that isn't really relevant here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `stringr` without any looping or `apply`ing:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("abc", "def", "ghi"),
                 col2 = c("foo ~xyz~", "~xyz~ bar", "blah ~xyz~ blah"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df$col2_replaced = str_replace(df$col2, "~xyz~", df$col1)
```

Output:

```
> df
  col1            col2 col2_replaced
1  abc       foo ~xyz~       foo abc
2  def       ~xyz~ bar       def bar
3  ghi blah ~xyz~ blah blah ghi blah
```

Comment: Awesome! I like this so much more than the route I was hoping to go for.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `apply` like so:

```
df$col2 <- apply(df, 1, 
             function(row) gsub(pattern="~xyz~", replacement=row["col1"], x=row["col2"]))
#   col1          col2
# 1  abc       foo abc
# 2  def       def bar
# 3  ghi blah ghi blah
```

Here it is with `mapply` (a.k.a. "multivariate apply") instead:

```
df$col2 <- mapply(
             function(rep, string) gsub(pattern="~xyz~", replacement=rep, x=string),
             df$col1, df$col2)
#   col1          col2
# 1  abc       foo abc
# 2  def       def bar
# 3  ghi blah ghi blah
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I need to do more research about `mapply`--that one's hard to keep straight in my head.